# GlowRoot for WSO2 EI

Tags: wso2, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

Is there a way to integrate web services that hosted in [WSO2 EI](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI620/WSO2+Enterprise+Integrator+Documentation) in [Glowroot](https://glowroot.org)?
Currently, WSO2 Carbon UI Request(9443) is log in Glowroot **Web Transaction**.
But when I request in Web Services(8280) there's no log in Glowroot **Web Transaction**.
[image]